# Is this concurrent code using processes not essentially sequential - Pyhon multi prcoessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

In trying to understand concurrency with multiprocessing I've written below code which shares reading and writing to a `Queue` between multiple processes:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool
class QueueFun():

    def writing_queue(self, work_tasks):
        while True:
            print("Writing to queue")
            work_tasks.put(1)
            time.sleep(.5)

    def read_queue(self, work_tasks):
        while True:
            print('Reading from queue')
            work_tasks.get()
            time.sleep(.5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = QueueFun()
    work_tasks = Queue()
    processes = []


    write_processes = []
    read_processes = []
    for i in range(0, 3):
        write_processes.append(Process(target=q.writing_queue,
                                 args=(work_tasks,)))
    for i in range(0, 3):
        read_processes.append(Process(target=q.read_queue,
                                 args=(work_tasks,)))

    for p in write_processes:
        p.start()
    for p in read_processes:
        p.start()

    print('Joining write_processes')
    for p in write_processes:
        print('Joining thread' , p)
        p.join()
    print('Joining read_processes')
    for p in read_processes:
        p.join()
```

produces:

```
Joining write_processes
Joining thread <Process name='Process-1' pid=2432 parent=2430 started>
Writing to queue
Reading from queue
Writing to queue
Writing to queue
Reading from queue
Reading from queue
```

Before I manually kill the thread.

My understanding of `join()` is `t.join()` causes the main thread to wait for `t` to finish. Therefore is this not essentially a sequential call as I need to wait for each thread to finish before the next thread is invoked. I'm aiming to execute each of these processes in parallel but it appears they execute sequentially? How to start lists of `write_processes` and `read_processes` concurrently?

Update:

The code for `print('Joining read_processes')` is not processed as 'Joining read_processes' is not printed to console. But 'Reading from queue' is printed to console so function `read_queue` is started. Why is code `print('Joining read_processes')` skipped? Therefore, as t.join() causes main thread to wait for t to finish.join() blocks the main thread it doesn't block other threads from starting?

Comment: Note that queues are inherently about "sequentialising" concurrent actions, which should be apparent from their name. If you want to see concurrency, the code should actually *do* something concurrent. This means significant parts of *independent* actions and only little synchronisation.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi in the above example then I do not need     "print('Joining read_processes')
    for p in read_processes:
        p.join()" as the main thread is already blocked during "for p in write_processes: loop" and by extension, I just need to block one of the threads, not all 6?

Comment: You do not need to block any threads (actually, processes in this case). You should only ``.join`` a thread/process that you know *will finish on its own*. Both ``writing_queue`` and ``read_queue`` are infinite loops that will *never* finish, there is no point waiting for them.

Comment: No, why would it stop the other threads from starting? Your program starts the threads, **then** it waits for them to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thread**.join() is a blocking call (for the *calling* thread) to wait for **Thread** to complete before continuing. Thus every task started after a join() will be sequential to the joined threads. In your example it does not make your processes sequential.
Your processes are started one after the other which is normal, but that doesn't mean they are not executed in parallel

Comment: "Thread.join() is a blocking call to wait for all threads to complete before continuing." I think is incorrect as from the docs : "Block the calling thread until the process whose join() method is called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs." (src: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) it appears the calling thread blocks all other threads from executing until the calling thread completes.

Comment: no, it doesnt block the threads, it blocks the main thread (from where you call join() until the joined thread(s) has/have completed. I edited the answer for more clarity

Comment: @Adrian As the docs say, ``join`` does "block *the calling thread*" (the one that executes ``join()``), not any others.